# Cakephp force download makes site useless

Tags: cakephp, force-download

I am facing a rare problem with cakephp force download code. Below is my code:-

```
public function download($cid = null,$id = null) {

  $this->viewClass= 'Media';
  $Video = $this->Video->findById($id);
  $ext = explode('.',$Video['Video']['name']);
  $params = array(
        'id'        => $Video['Video']['name'],
        'name'      => $Video['Video']['title'],
        'download'  => true,
        'extension' => $ext[1],
        'path'      => APP . 'webroot/movies/clips_mov'.DS
   );
  $this->set($params);
}
```

This is the code I am using since ages and almost all the tutorials on the web are point to this code only. Below is the code of download link code onclick of which executes this code and file starts downloading:-

```
 <a  href="<?php echo Router::url('/videos/download/1/'.$video['Download']     
 ['video_id'], true);?>" >Download</a>
```

Now the problem starts. When I click the download link the file downloading starts and goes on well. But during the time file is downloading the site becomes useless. No matter on whatever link or button i click on the site the page keeps on loading but never loads. The files are bit large most of them are from 200MB to 1GB . The site becomes again useful and starts working fine when the file download is finish or if I cancel the downloading. But during the download the site becomes useless and we cannot browse it till then.
Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The `Media` view has been deprecated since CakePHP 2.3, if you are using CakePHP >= 2.3, send a file instead (http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#cake-response-file).

Comment: On which kind of server are you running this site?

Comment: Your problem is going to be session locking - you're holding the session open whilst serving the download (why are you serving files that are in the webroot _at all_? Just point at/redirect to publicly accessible file).